# Shorten the path to an ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, user-interface, imageicon

When creating an ImageIcon in Java, is there a way to shorten the path to the file instead of having `C:\Users\John\Documents\Images\image.gif` could I just have the path be `image.gif`?

I have tried putting the image in the same directory as the Java class but it does not locate the image.

Comment: Is `image.gif` an application resource (e.g. is it used as a background for the app., or an icon for a button or menu item)?

Comment: can you post your code.... It seems like the relative path you have provided isnt working correctly

Comment: image.gif is an ImageIcon added to a JLable in a JFrame. If I go `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.gif")` and the image.gif is in the same directory as the class it does not load it but if I put in the whole path to the image it does load it. I don't want to hardcode the full path to the images because then the application probably wouldn't work on a different computer i.e the computers in college.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(Test.class.getResource("test.gif"));`

In this case, Test.class and test.gif are in the same location.  Normally, you would structure it like so:

- src/com/mywebsite/Test.java
- resources/com/mywebsite/test.gif

Set both src and resources as source folders.  Then when you compile, test.gif will be outputted to the same location as Test.class.